# How to post error messages to the HTML from Struts2 outside of Action class

Tags: java, spring, validation, jsp, struts2

I have a register program. When I insert a record on the database, I'll instantiate a class and invoke the method `insert()`. When I insert a the same record, of course there is a duplicate data error and tons of error messages. I want to capture it with `try` and `catch`. I can do that. However, I have no idea how to display the message to the JSP.

What I have understand, in an action class, the `validate()` method and the `validation.xml` is run first. The insert duplicate error happened after those methods are invoked.

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import lotmovement.business.crud.InsertUserProfile;
import lotmovement.business.entity.UserProfile;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static String userId;
    private static String password;
    private static String firstName;
    private static String lastName;
    private static int securityLevel;

    @Override
     public String execute() {    
         ApplicationContext context = 
                 new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

          InsertUserProfile iup = 
                 (InsertUserProfile)context.getBean("insertuserprofile");
         iup.Insert();       

      return SUCCESS;
    }
```

**Here is my insert user profile method of**

```
 public void Insert() {          
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    UserProfile up = (UserProfile)context.getBean("userprofile");
    RegisterAction ra = (RegisterAction)context.getBean("registeraction");
    EntityStart es = (EntityStart)context.getBean("entitystart");

    es.StartDbaseConnection();

    up.setUserId(ra.getUserId());
    up.setFirstName(ra.getFirstName());
    up.setLastName(ra.getLastName());
    up.setPassword(ra.getPassword());
    up.setSecurityLevel(ra.getSecurityLevel());

    es.StartPopulateTransaction(up);

    es.CloseDbaseConnection();        
}
```

**This is my JSP:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/register.css">
  <title>Register</title>
  <s:head />
</head>
<body>
<s:form method="POST" action="register" >
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <s:actionerror/>
      <s:fielderror/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <s:textfield label="UserID"     key="userId" maxLength="20"/>
  <s:password label="Password"    key="password" maxLength="20"/>
  <s:password label="retype-Password"  key="retypepassword" maxLength="20"/>
  <s:textfield label="Firstname"  key="firstName" maxLength="20"/>
  <s:textfield label="Lastname"   key="lastName" maxLength="20"/>
  <s:textfield label="SecurityLevel" key="securityLevel" maxLength="20"/>
  <s:submit   value="Register"/>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please consider using the S2 Spring plugin; you're doing a lot of manual work in your action that's both unnecessary and inefficient. Also, actions are instantiated per-request: static variables are Very Bad in almost all circumstances and will lead to race conditions and other indeterminate behavior, particularity under load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

1.define your own exception class

```
public class MyException extends Exception {}
```

2.throw this exception, if there is an exception in your `insert` method

```
if(insertError){
    throw new MyExecption("your message");
}
```

3.in the action class, invoke `insert method with try-catch block`

```
try{
    insert();
} catch(MyException me){
    addActionError(me.getMessage());
    return "anything_you_want";
}
```

4.you can show the message in the jsp using `<s:actionerror/>`

Comment: This is bad ever possible solution out there.

Comment: See my answer, there's a link in comments to the article that explains well.

Comment: @RomanC I read your acticle, in this case he cannot validate until he does db access, if you insist to override `validate` method, he has to access DB 2 times everytime he populates the action. one time check if the user already exist, another time to save the user. I think you were the downvote. Please think about your solution and give me my score back.

Comment: You don't understand, db access is not the question, and it may have to access as many times as needed until the validation process. ORM undertake all db accesses for you.

Comment: @StevenBenitez sorry for disturbing you, can you pls explain this. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are `addActionError` and `addFieldError` methods at the `ActionSupport`. You can catch any errors inside the `validate` method. And invoke these methods if the wrong data is submitted. Once applied the request will dispatch to the `input` result. In the JSP you can use 
`<s:actionerror` and `<s:fielderror` to display errors you've added by the methods above.

Comment: do you mean you can use the ActionSupport even if it is outside the action class? And if I place a validate method on my insertrecord class, the validate method will still be the first one triggered?

Comment: no, your action should extend `ActionSupport`, which has override `validate` method.

Comment: yup that is my problem because what i did was. Actionclass---> insertrecord class. The error happend in insertrecord class's insertmethod. insertrecord is already outside of the actionclass? Sorry for my stupid questions am a very begginer on this. thanks

Comment: You could write a code that checks if you can insert a record or not and call this code from `validate` method. If negative result then do what I answered this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Roman. So try catch should not be inside the insert method. but on the action class instead. :)

Comment: That's why a validation used if you can prevent unnecessary exceptions thrown, `RuntimeException`. Do validate the data before insert, don't relay on the database. And don't mess up logic with validation in the execute. Separate the validation from the actual code.

Comment: okay i will do that :) thank you very much. I will use the validation() method in the action class and create a class to validate if record exist. Thanks you for the wise suggestions guru :)

Comment: [this link may help you](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/01/19/webwork-validation.html)

Comment: Returning input result is like a validation does but it's not a validation itself.

Comment: is `return INPUT` what you mean `bad`, he can return anything he wants, that is not what man have to do to show the msg.

Comment: and I don't think, this is the validation problem.